# Can I repair an enchanted iron pickaxe with an iron ingot and an anvil?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have an iron pickaxe with the Fortune enchantment which I'd like to extend the life of. If I try to repair it with an anvil using an iron ingot, will it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this works though you may need more than one ingot to fully repair it. It's also worth bearing in mind that doing this will cost you experience.

Comment: It will definitely be worth the experience. It took me about 10 attempts enchanting iron pickaxes before I got one with Fortune!